# Rails 3 Flowplayer Gem Usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, haml, flowplayer

I'm attempting to use the [flowplayer gem](https://github.com/jetviper21/flowplayer-gem) in my Rails 3 app.  I've followed the installation instructions

> Flowplayer Helper for Rails 3
>   applications
>
> 1. gem 'flowplayer' in your gem file
> 2. rails g flowplayer or rails g flowplayer commercial
> 3. add javascript_include_tag 'flowplayer.min.js' to your
>      application layout
> 4. read below
>
> Usage
>
> For JQuery
>
> = flowplayer_for :video, '/flowplayer.swf', 'jquery' do
>   |player|
>     - player.playlist [{:url => "video_still.jpg" }, {:url =>
>   "video_512x288.flv", :autoPlay =>
>   false, :autoBuffering => true }]
>     - player.onLoad do
>       - 'this.unmute();'
>
> For Prototype
>
> = flowplayer_for :video, '/flowplayer.swf', 'prototype' do
>   |player|
>     - player.playlist [{:url => "video_still.jpg" }, {:url =>
>   "video_512x288.flv", :autoPlay =>
>   false, :autoBuffering => true }]
>     - player.onLoad do
>       - 'this.unmute();'
>
> Configs are the same ones here
>
> http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/index.html
>   TODO
>
> More documentation

After Step 1 I executed

```
bundle install
```

Which was successful.

For Step 2, I executed the first option

```
rails g flowplayer
```

Which was successful.

For Step 3, I added

```
= javascript_include_tag 'flowplayer.min.js'
```

to the head of my application.html.haml file; which was successful.

For Step 4, I added

```
%a#video{:style => "display:block;width:512px;height312px;"}
```

to my home.html.haml file; which was successful and the equivalent of

```
<a id='video' style='display:block;width:512px;height312px;'>
```

as per [this HTML2HAML converter](http://html2haml.heroku.com/).

Now I've come to the last portion.  I am using jQuery, but I have no idea where to put this last snippet of code.

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is old but for anyone else - you can put the last bit of code right after the rest of your code.  Caveat:  There is a bug in the latest flowplayer gem.  flowplayer_for only takes two parameters (causing it to always use jQuery) while the example shows three parameters.  I've sent the author a pull request to change it.

So (in haml):

```
- content_for :head do
  = javascript_include_tag "flowplayer.min.js"

%a#video{:style => "display:block;width:512px;height312px;"}

= flowplayer_for :video, '/flowplayer.swf'do |player|
  - player.playlist [{:url => "video_still.jpg" }, {:url => "video_512x288.flv", :autoPlay => false, :autoBuffering => true }] 
  - player.onLoad do 
    - 'this.unmute();'
```

Comment: Hi I followed all the steps but I get following error when page is rendered: `undefined method `flowplayer_for' for #<#<Class:0x007fea94ae0ed0>:0x007fea92419220>`
Any suggestions regarding this? Thanks!

Comment: It's been so long, I really don't remember.  But if it doesn't know `flowplayer_for` either that method isn't in the gem anymore, or you haven't included/installed the gem.  Sorry for the lack of help.